# Gradle cmd command to package Quarkus Gradle app

Tags: gradle, quarkus

Just build a small quarkus app with gradle  and trying to package it. In maven we have command -"mvn clean package" to package it. Do we have something similar in gradle.

To check what all options we have, ran the command "gradlew task" from root of project. Got the below details. There is no mention of package related task.

C:\Personal\project\ImportFromHere\quarkus-crud>gradlew task

### Build tasks

assemble - Assembles the outputs of this project.

build - Assembles and tests this project.

buildDependents - Assembles and tests this project and all projects that depend on it.

buildNeeded - Assembles and tests this project and all projects it depends on.

classes - Assembles main classes.

clean - Deletes the build directory.

jar - Assembles a jar archive containing the main classes.

nativeTestClasses - Assembles native test classes.

quarkusGeneratedSourcesClasses - Assembles quarkus generated sources classes.

quarkusTestGeneratedSourcesClasses - Assembles quarkus test generated sources classes.

testClasses - Assembles test classes.

### Build Setup tasks

init - Initializes a new Gradle build.

wrapper - Generates Gradle wrapper files.

### Documentation tasks

javadoc - Generates Javadoc API documentation for the main source code.

### Help tasks

buildEnvironment - Displays all buildscript dependencies declared in root project 'quarkus-crud'.

dependencies - Displays all dependencies declared in root project 'quarkus-crud'.

dependencyInsight - Displays the insight into a specific dependency in root project 'quarkus-crud'.

help - Displays a help message.

javaToolchains - Displays the detected java toolchains. [incubating]

outgoingVariants - Displays the outgoing variants of root project 'quarkus-crud'.

projects - Displays the sub-projects of root project 'quarkus-crud'.

properties - Displays the properties of root project 'quarkus-crud'.

tasks - Displays the tasks runnable from root project 'quarkus-crud'.